# Adding this project as a reference would cause a circular dependency mvvm

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Well I saw many solutions on this type of the problem but I just can't solve my problem. I work on some wpf/mvvm application. My app is structured like this:

- One project for ViewModel
- One project for View
- One wcf service project

So the problem is this: I need to assign new datacontext to my window, from my viewmodel class. Something like this (in my view model class):

```
SomeWindow window = new SomeWindow();
window.DataContex = this.someViewModel;
```

Problem is i can't access my View classes. I added reference of my viewmodel into my view project, but can't add reference of my view into my viewmodel becouse I get the above error.
How can I solve this??

Comment: Move references, how else?  WCF shouldn't reference anybody, view should reference VM and possibly WCF, VM should reference WCF and not the view.  If types are in the wrong assemblies, move them.

Answer (score 3):

I cannot understand why it's necessary to assign data context in viewModels project (why not in Views project). But if you need to that this way, the most common approach is to create another (middle) project for those purposes. This new project will have references to the Views project and ViewModels project.

From the other hand ViewModels and Views are often in the same project (just in other folders/namespaces), so in this case that problem doesn't exists.

Comment: I didn't describe why I need to do it this way becouse I wanted to stay short and just stick to the point of my problem. Anyway I did try to add middle project for those purposes but just I got the same error. I could add reference of my View but then i cold not add the reference of my ViewModel.

Comment: Middle project should have references to both (views project, viewModels project), this is why it is used

Comment: Ok I made some middle project with references but when I make an object of my window class, I can only use initialize commponents and nothing else. How do I access DataContext?

Answer (score 1):

a viewmodel has no need to "know"/ reference the view. so you dont need a reference in your viewmodel project.

if you wanna change a datacontext for a view - you should simply change the "workspace" property of the viewmodel which is bind to that view.